# How to use ValueResolver if field type does not have a default constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have model with property:

```
public class MyModel{
       public SelectList PropertyTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

And I have ValueResolver

```
public class MyPropertyValueResolver : ValueResolver<ProductProperty, SelectList>
{
    protected override SelectList ResolveCore(ProductProperty source)
    {
        myList = .......;
        return new SelectList(myList, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

Then I configure mapping

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
          .ForMember(s => s.PropertyTypeList, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<MyPropertyValueResolver>());
```

But it says me that

```
Type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not have a default constructor
```

What I should to do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than automapping to a SelectList, have you considered automapping to a simple Array, and then using a Get-only property to wrap this as a SelectList?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2078865/169334) describes the approach.

Also, from the same SO question, there is the [ConstructedBy](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers) idea, as well as a way to use `MapFrom` to do this directly.